# Configuration wizard start and shut down

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, weblogic12c

I installed Weblogic version 12c 12.2.1.4 on Windows 10 64bit.Jdk version I used was 1.8.0_271. Set up java home and paths . I did not have any problems related to the installation, but  when 2nd step (domain create) configuration wizard start and shuts down immediately. How can i fix or what i miss out ?

Answer (score 0):

If the graphical wizard installation graphical interface you use is always turned off, it may be your JDK reason. It is recommended that you use the CMD command window to install with the text interface.